# Is there a way to find a basis of the row and column spaces of a matrix in R?

Tags: r, linear-algebra

I was posed this question by a co-worker and the answer is expected of me. Being quite new to R, as well as only being halfway through my first linear algebra course, hours of searching did not yield an answer. Any help here would be much appreciated!

I understand this question is fairly vague and not detailed, but that is exactly how it was posed to me. I will try to add any details if asked.

This is also my first question on here, so I apologize if I am not properly posing a question. Feel free to critique me, I am here to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rref(A) function to define the row and null space from the pracma package. The row space will be the cols in which have a leading 1 and null/col space will be the the number of columns less the row space. So code rref(as.matrix(A)) then write a bit to find the pivot columns in your reduced matrix and count your columns. The rest is simple arithmetic.

Comment: The rref() function was helpful. Now that I have my rref matrix, I'm having trouble separating the column space from the rest of the matrix. I understand that a column with a leading 1 is part of the column space, and the other columns are part of the null space. So if, in a 5 col matrix, columns 1,2, and 4 have leading 1's, that is the basis of the column space. How I can determine and display that with R code is my problem now.

Comment: You can sum the vector of the column. Something similar to:

     A<-rref(A)
     colspace<-0

     for(i 1:in length(A){
         if(sum(A[,i])==1){
             colspace<-colspace+1
                                   }
                          }
     Rowspace<-length(A)-colspace

This code is untested but for you to get the idea of a way to do it.

Comment: I just checked and Null{MASS} would work outside of a hand rolled solution. From the nullity you can find the other attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind the [four subspaces](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/ax-b-and-the-four-subspaces/) of a matrix:

[image]

Creating a matrix with 3 vectors in R4, only two linearly independent:

```
> v1 <- c(3,5,11,-1)
> v2 <- c(45,-2,5,23)
> v3 <- v1 -2*v2
> 
> (M <- cbind(v1,v2,v3))
     v1 v2  v3
[1,]  3 45 -87
[2,]  5 -2   9
[3,] 11  5   1
[4,] -1 23 -47
```

Determining the **RANK**:

```
> # RANK:
> nrow(rref(M)[apply(rref(M)[,-1], 1, function(x) !all(x==0)),])
[1] 2
```

Generating a basis for the **COLUMN SPACE**, which lives in R4 the result (b) of all `Mx=b`:

```
> (Col_sp <- t(rref(t(M))[apply(rref(t(M)), 1, function(x) !all(x==0)),]))
            v1         v2
[1,] 1.0000000  0.0000000
[2,] 0.0000000  1.0000000
[3,] 0.2034632  2.0779221
[4,] 0.4891775 -0.4935065
```

Generating a basis for the orthogonal subspace to the column space in R4 (i.e. the **LEFT NULL SPACE** or null space of the transposed) or x in `tr(M)x = 0`:

```
library(MASS)
> (Left_Null <- Null(M))
           [,1]         [,2]
[1,] -0.2369092 -0.399278229
[2,] -0.8051370  0.413649975
[3,]  0.4573183 -0.004747012
[4,]  0.2940891  0.818198057
```

Do these two vectors fulfill the condition `tr(M)x = 0`?

```
> round(t(M)%*%Left_Null,10)
   [,1] [,2]
v1    0    0
v2    0    0
v3    0    0
```

Check!

Are these two subspaces indeed orthogonal?

```
> round(t(Col_sp) %*% Left_Null, 10)
   [,1] [,2]
v1    0    0
v2    0    0
```

Check!

Generating a basis for the **ROW SPACE** living in R3 or solutions (x) to `Mx = b`:

```
> (Row_sp <- rref(M)[apply(rref(M), 1, function(x) !all(x==0)),])
     v1 v2 v3
[1,]  1  0  1
[2,]  0  1 -2
```

Generating a basis for the **RIGHT NULL SPACE** (null space of the column space) or solutions to `Mx=0` living in R3:

```
> (Right_Null <- Null(t(M)))
           [,1]
[1,] -0.4082483
[2,]  0.8164966
[3,]  0.4082483
```

Is `Mx=0` fulfilled?

```
> round(M %*% Right_Null, 10)
     [,1]
[1,]    0
[2,]    0
[3,]    0
[4,]    0
```

Check!

Are these last two subspaces orthogonal?

```
> round(Row_sp %*% Right_Null,10)
     [,1]
[1,]    0
[2,]    0
```

Check!